# Identifying space and quotient map

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to  to understand an example from Munkres book which illustrates that product of two  quotient maps may not be quotient map.

I have spent a whole day trying to understand this proof and eventually I have two questions which I cannot answer by myself.

**1)** Since $X=\mathbb{R}$ with usual topology and $X^*$ its partition  with elements $\{\mathbb{Z}_+, \{x\}\}$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}_+$ and other singletons. I cannot understand two moments here:

1.1. What does mean indentifying the subset $\mathbb{Z}_+$ to a point $b$?  Can anyone give a rigorous meaning to this phrase?

1.2. Also how looks like the function $p:X\to X^{*}$?

**2)** Why it is obvious that the set $U$ is saturated with respect to $(p,i)$? I see that $\mathbb{Z}_+\times \{q\} \subset U$ for each $q\in \mathbb{Q}$. But how it follows that this set $U$ is saturated?

I would be very grateful if you can answer my questions with details.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Munkres explains this in the definition on p.139. In the present case the partition $X^*$ has only one non-trivial (which means *non-singleton*) element. More generally, "identifying a subset $A$ of a space $Y$" to a point yields a space usually denoted as $Y/A$. Its elements are the sets $\{ y \}$ with $y \notin A$ and the set $A$. The quotient map $p : Y \to Y/A$ is given by $p(y) =  \{ y \}$ für $y \notin A$ and $p(y) = A$ for $y \in A$.

2) Let us more generally consider an arbitrary surjection $r : Y \to Z$. Then a subset $M \subset Y$ is saturated if and only if for all $y \in M$ we have $r^{-1}r(y) \subset M$.

Let us look at $r = p \times i$. If $(x,q) \in X \times \mathbb Q$, then $r^{-1}r(x,q) = (p  \times i)^{-1}(p(x),q) = p^{-1}p(x) \times \{q\}$. You know that $\mathbb{Z}_+\times \{q\} \subset U$ for each $q\in \mathbb{Q}$. Let $(x,q) \in U$. If $x \in \mathbb Z_+$, then $r^{-1}r(x,q) = \mathbb{Z}_+\times \{q\} \subset U$. If $x \notin \mathbb Z_+$, then $r^{-1}r(x,q) = \{x\} \times \{q\} \subset U$.

Comment: It's a really nice answer! It helped me a lot. But when i was reviewing everything one more time I have noticed one moment and I would be very thankful if you can explain it to me. We see that $\mathbb{Z}_+\times \{0\}\subset U$ then how it follows that $(b,0)\in U'$? What is $b$ here? After it they have done some steps which is clear to me. I see that $p^{-1}(W)$ is open in $X$ and why it contains $\mathbb{Z}_+$? This is everything what I wanted to ask. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The *points* of the space $X^*$ are *subsets* of the space $X$.Munkres denotes the point $\mathbb Z_+ \in X^*$ by $b$ (recall "by identifying the subset $\mathbb Z_+$ to a point $b$"). For $x \in \mathbb Z_+$ we get $r(x,0) = (p(x),0) = (b,0)$. This shows $(b,0) \in U' = r(U)$.

Comment: So you mean he is denoting $\mathbb{Z}_+$ by $b$, right?

Comment: The points of $X^*$ are the sets $\{ x\}$ with $x  \in X \setminus \mathbb Z_+$ and the set $ \mathbb Z_+$. Munkres writes $b  = \mathbb Z_+$. But $b$ is no number, it is an infinite set of numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining! You helped me a lot!